# How to use yahoo contact api in android application?

Tags: android, contacts, yahoo-api

I want to fetch all email id and name from yahoo contact api [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/). I have read a documentation for yahoo contact api,by login by my account I have created api key and consumer key, I am able to see json response online,now my problem is that how to integrate such thing in android,(i.e how to get such json response in android),there is a lack of documentation for android regarding this api. I have also read [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Fantasy-Sports-API/Yahoo-API-for-Android-application/1325574236600-f1a6913c-07c4-4ef8-85d9-a33a6662ba54), but it making me more confuse,can any one guide me on a proper way that how to use this api in android application.

Thanks